# Issue with declaring global variable in c++?

Tags: c++

I am not that much experienced in c++. Here I am declaring two global variable
n and cache.This is my code for the same.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
#include<vector>
int n;
int cache[n][n];
int find_max_profit(vector<int> &v,int l,int r)
{
if(l>r)
{
    return 0;
}
else
{
    int year=l+n-r;
    return max(find_max_profit(v,l+1,r)+year*v[l],find_max_profit(v,l,r-1)+year*v[r]);
}
}
int main()
{
    cout<<"enter the number of wines"<<endl;
cin>>n;
int i,j;
cout<<"enter the prices"<<endl;
vector<int> v;
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<n;j++)
    {
        cache[i][j]=-1;
    }
}
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    int num;
    cin>>num;
    v.push_back(num);
}
int max=find_max_profit(v,0,n-1);
cout<<"maximum profit is "<<max<<endl;
return 0;
}
```

When i compile this code I get the following error:

```
||=== Build: Debug in selling wine (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
/home/kaminey/makichut/selling wine/main.cpp|5|error: array bound is not     an integer constant before ‘]’ token|
/home/kaminey/makichut/selling wine/main.cpp|5|error: array bound is not an integer constant before ‘]’ token|
/home/kaminey/makichut/selling wine/main.cpp||In function ‘int main()’:|
/home/kaminey/makichut/selling wine/main.cpp|29|error: ‘cache’ was not   declared in this scope|
||=== Build failed: 3 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

But this should get compiled, I want to know what is wrong with my code here.

Comment: what is the value of `n` in `int cache[n][n];`?

Comment: @silentboy n is input.

Comment: @user2738777 You need the value of `n` known at compile time. You can't magically expand it at runtime. Use `std::vector` or something else appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

You can't declare an array using size as an input integer. Either you have to depend on probable array size 10 like as follows;

```
int cache[10][10];
```

otherwise you can use `std::vector<>`  instead array.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this.
Compiler should know how to calculate array size.

```
int n;
int cache[n][n];
```

You can dynamically allocate cache array.

Comment: OKay , so any idea?,specially in dp questions how do we create a table because we can know input at the run time.

Comment: @user2738777 In dp solution, you just know how many states are there. Aren't you?

Answer (score 0):

Possibility solutions:

```
cache = new int*[n];
for( int i = 0; i < n; i++ ) {
    cache[i] = new int[n];
}
```

or

```
std::vector< std::vector<int> > cache;
cache.resize( n, std::vector<int>( n, 0 ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

the first Error is that the Array bound of cache (n) must be Const .. or you can make your array as dynamic array like this..

```
int **cache=new int*[n];
for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
cache[i]=new int[n];
}
```

Comment: the first Error is that the Array bound of cache (n) must be Const ..
or you can make your array as dynamic array
like this..

Comment: Can you add any explanation of your code to the answer post instead of the comments? Comments are easily missed or deleted.

Answer (score 0):

It is a non-issue that your variables are global (The fact that they're global is  more related to best-practices and scoping, but is unrelated to your compile error.) The issue instead is that the compiler does not know how large your `cache` is at compile time.

I'm not super clear on the reasoning behind why, but when you declare an array in C++ that is NOT dynamically allocated, the array-size must be known at the time of compilation. Since your current version of the code requires user-input to define the size of the array, the compiler does not know the size at the time of compilation ("Could the user want `n = 10`? Or perhaps `n = 100`? I do not know how much room to give `cache` ]: ").

In order to get around this, I would personally try to follow the other users' solutions; either dynamically allocate your `cache`, or use a `std::vector`.

[Here](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/61-arrays-part-i/) is some general information on arrays. I have also quoted some relevant lines from this link that touch upon your issue:

> A **fixed array** (also called a fixed length array or fixed size array) is an array where the length is known at compile time.

and

> Because fixed arrays have memory allocated at compile time, that introduces two limitations:

- > Fixed arrays cannot have a length based on either user input or some other value calculated at runtime.
- > Fixed arrays have a fixed length that can not be changed.